# Changing dropdown options

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts, onchange

I am developing a musical store. In that application in `makepayment.jsp` I have four links for user choice and based on user choice I want change the options in my dropdown. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`onChange`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp) event of the input component, and [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp).

Answer (score 0):

get the combobox object by id or name in the javascript.

```
<select id="myCombo" name="myCombo">
</select>


var opt = document.createElement("option");
opt.text="something"
opt.value="something"
document.getElementById("myCombo").options.add(opt);
```

also you can assign id to options.

Comment: Please stop referring `select-list` or `dropdown`, as `combobox`. Its not a combo in any sense. Further, refer to the BalusC's edit to the original question, here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4496605/revisions .